# Animate a simple FBX model in Blender

Tags: animation

I want to animate the following arrow in Blender so that the left and right triangle can flip, like a bird (ignore the white line in the background), but I have no experience with Blender before. So how can I approach this problem?

I want to use this animation in Unity if this makes any difference.

[image: Simple FBX model]

Answer (score 0):

For practice, you can take an animation approach in Blender but for a simple animation like that, I would personally make the animation within Unity. It will give you a lot more control when making a game.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Unfortunately, I also have no experience with animation with Unity. Can you point a direction for me? Thanks!

Comment: This might be a bit overkill/overwhelming but this is the [official Unity tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/animation) on Animation. Unity Animation is very easy it shouldn't take you to long to get the hang of it if you have a little animation experience.